# How can I get all configuration with the same value for the property "company.server"?

Tags: java, configuration, apache-commons

I am new to Apache Commons Configuration and got stuck. I have a growing number of servers, on each server a number of apps are running. Each app represents an installation for a specific customer.

For simplicity reason I shrink here the configuration example here to this. How can I get all the configurations that are related to, for example, server01 (see XML below)?

[XML configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j9ha.jpg)

```
Properties configs = mCombinedConfig.getProperties("company.server");
```

When my codes executes the `getProperties` statement I get an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'server01' does not contain an equals sign
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.getProperties(AbstractConfiguration.java:1165)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.getProperties(AbstractConfiguration.java:1119)
    at com.atoss.alm.helpertemp.CommonsConfigurationExample.json(CommonsConfigurationExample.java:138)
    at com.atoss.alm.helpertemp.CommonsConfigurationExample.main(Unknown Source)
```

What is wrong with the `getProperties` statement?

Comment: review your properties file: `'server01' does not contain an equals sign at `

Comment: Please advise me what is wrong, with the configuration file. You can see the xml by clicking the link above. This is one of the numerous lines with the value "server01" as value for server: <server>server01</server>

Comment: you are supposed to use properties file instead of xml files aren't you?

Comment: I can not use property files and  org.apache.commons.configuration2.CombinedConfiguration offers the method. 
However, maybe getProperties() is the wrong approach. I need to find out  which apps of our customers are installed on a specific server.